# connection.open hanging/freezing. What is wrong with my connection string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-connection, connection-string

I wanted to make my connection string dynamic so I don't have to recompile my code for each new user.

my old connection string:

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\Storm\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SeaSideBlissVersion2\SeaSideBlissVersion2\ShopDb.mdf";Integrated Security=True

My config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>

  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and then some code in my db class:

```
 class DB
{

    static string conn;
    static SqlConnection _conn;

    public DB()
    {
        conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
        _conn = new SqlConnection(conn);
    }

    public void dbAddItem(string name, string measurement, string PLU)
    {
        string query = string.Format("INSERET INTO tblItems (ItemName, Measurement, Stock, PLUNumber) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3})", name, measurement, 0, PLU);
        _conn.Open();

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, _conn);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        _conn.Close();

    }
}
```

And used the following references:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

When I call my **dbAddItem** method it seems to hang at **_conn.Open()**

I'm assuming there's something wrong with my connection string? I've looked it up and nothing that I found helped.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Express?

Comment: I am using SQLServer

Comment: There are different versions of SQL Server, and their connection strings might differ from each other. Do you know which one you specifically are using?

Comment: hmmm ok uhm, well honestly I'm not completely sure... I'm using vs 2015, I just right clicked on my project in the solution explorer, clicked "add" -> "new item" and then added a new service-based database. That made a new mdf file. So yea I hope that helps.

Comment: Include the name of the path to the `.mdf` file in your connectionstring.

Comment: Isn't that what the _Initial Catalog=ShopDB_ is for? the file is called ShopDB.mdf

Comment: I think you have to use the `AttachDbFilename` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems The mistake was obvious, once I put my .mdf db into the debug folder it worked. It makes sense because there is no "exact" directory to look in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you missed login info to the DB in the connection string.
Something like "uid=xxx;pwd=xxx".

Comment: I'm using windows authentication though?